# Multiply digits in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's say we have *list of numbers* and we want to multiply all numbers in it as long as product is digit.

For Example:

```
[2,2,5] => [4,5]

[3,3,7] => [9,7]

[5,5,5,5,5] => [5,5,5,5,5]
```

Can I somehow use `functools.reduce` here? What's pythonic way to solve this problem?

Comment: can you explain how you are getting those outputs

Comment: what if there is a zero?

Comment: First two is ok but [5,5,5,5,5] => [5,5,5,5,5] how?

Comment: I think OP means, as long as product is **single** digit.

Comment: @TomZych Yes, exactly.

Comment: @farhawa Let's assume for now, that list has only digits greater than 1.

Comment: what is the output of `[21,2,2,1]`?

Comment: @AhsanulHaque `[21,4]`

Comment: What about `[21, 2, 2, 21, 2]`, i.e. do the numbers to be multiply have to be adjacent?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be solved easily by a simple stateful algorithm:

```
def multiply_digits(lst):
    res = []
    for x in lst:
        if res and res[-1] * x < 10:
            res[-1] *= x
        else:
            res.append(x)
    return res
```

While there is an equivalent functional way (with `reduce`), that will not be as simple since you either need to reassemble the result list in each step, or carry the current number value separately.

Comment: What if I'd have input [3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2] and expect to get [3,8,8,8] and not [4,6,8,8] (so after join, I'd get smallest possible number, 3888 < 4688)?

Comment: @Adiqq That's far more complex and out of scope for this question. You can try to go from the back (using [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed) in Python), but you probably need a clever algorithm (or just brute force all possibilities) to find the number which yields the smallest result.

Answer (score 1):

This might do the trick:

```
def process(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    last = 1
    result = []
    for el in lst:
        if last * el >= 10:
            result.append(last)
            last = el
            continue
        last *= el
    result.append(last)
    return result
```

Comment: @DanielSanchez I assume that the order of numbers dosn't matter, i.e. we just won't reduce possible combinations. In case of phihag's answer the order matters, e.g. `[21, 2, 2, 1]` and `[2, 21, 2, 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is better I guess:

```
from numpy import product
reduce(lambda x , y : (x[0:-1]+[y*x[-1]] if product(x+[y])<10 else x+[y]) if len(x)>0 else [y]  ,[21,1,2,3,4,5,6],[])
```

Comment: This code just checks n-1 digits. It returns wrong results wrong for almost all inputs. For instance, I'd expect `[9, 2, 2] => [9, 4]`, `[8]` => `[8]`, `[2, 2, 3, 3] => [4,9]` .

Comment: Now check it again . Does that work.

Comment: No, it still fails the very first test I gave (`[9, 2, 2] => [9, 4]`). Plus, the updated version is horrendously inefficient, given it constantly constructs lists and calls `numpy.product` for a single multiplication.